# CSS images not aligning correctly

Tags: html, css, image

I'm having a problem with my CSS, I assume. I want the picture of the lipstick to align with the face image and have the nail one underneath both of them.

#### HTML

```
<center>
<div id="homepage-image preventOverflow homepageHero {{ section.settings.height }} {{ section.settings.color }} index-section">
  <div id="left">
    <img width=600px type="image/jpeg" src="{{ 'lipstickpink.jpg' | asset_url}}" />

   <!-- <img width=600px type="image/jpeg" src="{{ 'shadow.jpg' | asset_url}}" /> -->
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <div id="top-right">
      <img width=900px type="image/png" src="{{ 'faceglam.png' | asset_url}}" />


    </div>
    <div id="bottom-right">
        <img width=600px type="image/jpeg" src="{{ '11_Vertigo_1024x1024.jpg' | asset_url}}" />

    </div>
  </div>
  </div> </center>
```

#### CSS

```
#container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
    padding-top: $gutter*3;
  padding-bottom: $gutter*2;


}

#left > img:nth-of-type(1) {
  height: 85vh;
  width: 70vw;
}
#left > img:nth-of-type(2) {
  height: 65vh;
  width: 49vw;
}
#left, #right {
  display: inline-block;
}
#top-right, #bottom-right {
  display: block;
}
#top-right > img:nth-of-type(1) {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
#top-right > img:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 35vw;
  height: 60vh;
}

#bottom-right > img:nth-of-type(1) {
  width: 60vw;
  height: 60vh;
}
#bottom-right > img:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 25vh;
}
```

I have also provided an image of the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not completely clear how (i.e in which direction) you want them aligned. 
You have a lot of seemingly unnecessary divs - i wondered why.. so I have adjusted both HTML and CSS (used own images from internet)

If I got them in the wrong order, just adjust the images. I adjusted heights (re-adjustable obviously)- but hope you get the general gist!

Hope this helps

```css
#container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: $gutter*3;
  padding-bottom: $gutter*2;
}

#left{
margin-left:10%;
margin-right:10%;
}

#left > img:nth-of-type(1) {
 max-height:200px;
 padding:5px;
  height:auto;
}

#left > img:nth-of-type(2) {
 max-height:300px;
  padding:5px;
  height: 60vh;
}

#left,
#right {
  display: inline-block;
}

#right > img:nth-of-type(1) {
  max-height:300px;
  height: auto;
  margin-left:18vw;
  margin-right:18vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/czZtMqTum5GQOYL1NxogiEVZ57Zr5LG0chnil-p3YFTjl3WIQdrADqpaaATmyN-JGjey=h900" alt="face" />
    <img src="http://bpc.h-cdn.co/assets/16/38/480x480/gallery-1474299136-urban-decay-vice-pink-lipstick.jpg" alt="lipstick" />
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <img src="http://www.vipera.com.pl/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/20zestawy_lakier__w_do_artystycznego_zdobienia_paznokci________artistic_manicure_set___219.jpg" alt="nails" />
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/8bjjz5hy/)

Comment: **NOTE: center tags are obsolete in html5, use margin attributes instead!**